# Place an image where the user touches

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitouch

Basically touch screen image should appear where touched but doesn't work.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"BluePin.png"];
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant call on a UIImage as it only holds the image data, you have to use the UIImageView instead and then is should work.

So use this instead:

```
-(void) touchBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
UImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"BluePin.png"];
imageView.image = image;
[imageView drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)];
}
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Oops sorry was in a hurry writing the code i changed it now so there shouldnt be any issues any more :D